# Integrating standalone php application in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have created a small application , basically a quiz application ( I am about to launch that in a free web hosting website). I want to integrate that with Facebook. But there are mainly 2 issues.

1. I want the application to be used only by FB users who are member of a particular group (Its a closed group) which i created.
2. As soon as the quiz is over , the final score should be posted in the group wall.

PS: By integrate i mean , They can only begin the test when they signup using Facebook.
Any other ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things you'll need to do. Assuming you're using the FB JS SDK, you'll need to use the following...

- Request the publish_stream and user_groups extended permissions via FB.login
- Post to the group wall via FB.api, eg... FB.api('/GROUP_ID/feed', 'post', { message: 'yay someone completed the quiz' }, function(response) { alert(response); });

Partial example using FB JS SDK (group checking unimplemented)...

```
<a onclick="postToGroupWall()">Post msg to group wall</a>

<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'APP_ID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true , // parse XFBML
        oauth : true // Enable oauth authentication
    });  

    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse)
        {
            alert('Logged in!');

            // Check if user is in group using opengraph call (/me/groups) via FB.api

            // Do that here...
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Not logged in - do something');
        }
    }, { scope : 'publish_stream,user_groups' });
};

window.postToGroupWall = function()
{   
    var opts = {
        message : 'Yay I just completed the quiz',
        name : '',
        link : 'http://www....',
        description : 'Description here',
        picture : 'http://domain.com/pic.jpg'
    };

    FB.api('/GROUP_ID/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
    {
        if (!response || response.error)
        {
            alert('Posting error occured');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
};

</script>

<!-- FACEBOOK -->        
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  // replacing with an older version until FB fixes the cancel-login bug
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  //e.src = 'scripts/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<!-- END-OF-FACEBOOK -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to do with facebook (including, but not limited to, the exact requirements you have explained)can be achieved using Facebook Connect API. It is very comprehensive and I can't explain how you would do the whole thing in this answer. This is a good place to start:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/